# go language Automation testing

Tags: selenium, go, automation

Please someone help me out on go language automation testing

i have been working out manual coding for automation. Please help me any packages or framework available to run automation testing in go.

Answer (score 2):

Go provides its own testing package you can view it here

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

You can write your own tests a common layout is to write your file, then write a `_test.go` file to test e.g.

```
package.go
package_test.go
```

then you can test your file by running

`go test`

And bam, you're good to go

Here's a random test package from a random app for example: https://github.com/yohcop/openid-go/blob/master/redirect_test.go

Answer (score 2):

A plenty of them! You should check a list of tools for testing here: https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#testing

Answer (score 0):

Try http://goconvey.co

GoConvey also supports Go's native testing package.

Answer (score 0):

Go provides its own testing package you can view it here

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

Or you can get other pkg for testing, for example testify

https://github.com/stretchr/testify