# Automation in Go Lang - How to use browser automation like Selenium?

Tags: selenium, browser, go, automation

I am new to Golang. And I am looking for automating signup, login processes in a web app. Please suggest a good tool like Selenium and how can I implement it in the go language.

I want to do the following process automatically using Golang:

1. Start a browser. Currently, I'm using https://github.com/skratchdot/open-golang
2. Auto entry on the signup page and auto-submit a form.
3. Login check for the registered user. Everything needs to be done automatically for more users.

Comment: Does Selenium support `Go Lang?` I think no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588393/go-language-automation-testing

Comment: why golang and "a good tool"? golang, as a programming language has it's tools.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/knq/chromedp -- it allows you to drive various browsers without external dependencies using the Chrome Debugging Protocol.

Comment: WebDriver client written in golang to target all modern browsers   https://github.com/tebeka/selenium

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use GO for web automation testing - Selenium is a good option. Still it's nothing more than a library that allows you to interact with browsers. So you are going to need to develop your own framework or reuse someone already implemented.

My advice is to consider [Agouti](https://agouti.org/), since it supports [Ginkgo](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) BDD and xUnit [Gomega](http://onsi.github.io/gomega/). Everything else is pretty much the same from architectural perspective. You can design it like any other language binding. There are [common patterns](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesignPatterns) that appear over and over again in browser automation frameworks, like

- PageObjects: A simple abstraction of the UI of your web app.
- LoadableComponent: Modeling PageObjects as components.
- BotStyleTests: command-based approach

Another good resource for building your Test framework is the [xunitpatterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/) guide. It gives a great content overview of the patterns, smells and refactoring strategies you can use. Also look at this [test frameworks tutorial](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-automation-frameworks-selenium-tutorial-20/). It'll help you choose the most proper solution for your case.

My guess is that you are going to need some [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server support for

> everything needs to be done auto for more users.

Here is a [good article](http://jmcvetta.github.io/blog/2013/08/30/continuous-integration-for-go-code/) how-to achieve this with [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Playwright for Go](https://github.com/mxschmitt/playwright-go), which is a wrapper for the [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) project. Playwright provides a single API to automate Chromium, Firefox, and WebKit to automate browsers which was created by Microsoft. With it you interact with the sites, record videos, make screenshots, and emulate other browser specific behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

update:
you can use [Selenium for Golang](https://github.com/tebeka/selenium)